# Insert Symfony action or twig in WordPress page

Tags: php, wordpress, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I have a project with Wordpress and Symfony whit this estructure:

```
- project
-- symfony folder
-- wp-admin
-- wp-content
-- wp-includes
-- wp files
.
.
.
```

They work separately. In this way, the WordPress pages have a normal route:
http://mypage.com/?page_id=969

And the Symfony pages have their own routes: http://mypage.com/symfony/web/app_dev.php/page

But now I want to include the content of Symfony in a Wordpress page. There is a way to do it? Can I show the content of a Symfony page inside of a WordPress page?

Comment: It would certainly be possible, but the performance would be horrible. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Maybe pre-rendering the SF contents to an intermediate file and loading that into WP would be a better idea.